# Unable to Extract Value from URL in Jmeter

Tags: javascript, load, jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

I'm new to **JMeter tool.**

I have requirement to record an email transaction. There are many dynamic values which are passed as URL query string.

I'm unable extract those values using Reg-ex Extractor.

Those dynamic parameters values are used in the same HTTP request not in the next/subsequent request.

For example :

```
www.xyz.com/shva?123&abc=LLRRQQ;cdv=AABBCC.  

In the same http request contains parameter abc = LLRRQQ and cdv=AABBCC.
```

So how to dynamically extract from URL query string and pass it to the same request.

Any help would be highly appreciated !

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to extract parameters using `&` separator or you want to also separate with `;`?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract query string parameters and convert it to sampler arguments using [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) as follows:

```
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;

URI uri = sampler.getUrl().toURI();

List params = URLEncodedUtils.parse(uri, "UTF-8");

for (NameValuePair param : params) {    
    sampler.addArgument(param.getName(), param.getValue());
    //sampler.addEncodedArgument(param.getName(),param.getValue()); // if you need to encode parameter
}
```

Perhaps you'll need to do some extra coding around `123` and `;` bits, the code above works only with `parametername=parametervalue` "classic" URL parameters.

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for advanced guide on how to extend JMeter test via Beanshell scripting.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the same request then it means you control the parameters and already know them.

What is the full scenario of your request ?